# convert the given link to PDF not working when link is not hardcoded

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the given link to PDF. This works when I hardcode the link:

```
app.use('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  var b="https://www.google.com/";
    request({
        uri: b,
      }, async function(error, response, body) {
          console.log('html created');
        saveDataToPublicFolder(body, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).send('User not saved');
        return;
      }
      next();
    });
      });
  });
```

But when I use to pass the link, the code breaks:

```
app.use('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  var b=JSON.stringify(req.body.contents);
    request({
        uri: b,
      }, async function(error, response, body) {
          console.log('html created');
        saveDataToPublicFolder(body, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).send('User not saved');
        return;
      }
      next();
    });
      });
  });
```

Can someone  please help me.

Comment: what does **the code breaks** means? what error did you get? Have you tried checking the contents of `req.body.contents`

Comment: it means that saveDataToPublicFolder(body,) saves undefined instead of the output

Comment: whats the output ot `console.log(req.body)`?